# how to show a especific message error on display pdf

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, exception, http-headers

I'm trying to show a report PDF with spring, and i finally got it, but the problem appears when I have an exception or an error in my code. In this cases, I want to show especific messages in my app. The sping controller returns a ResponseEntity with the file pdf, and a code of http status.

I call this controller form my html template with a tag

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="co_<%= idFacturaF1 %>">
        <object class="pdfObject" data="<%= App.CONTEXT_PATH + '/api/certificadoOrigen/' + idFacturaF1%>#page=1&view=FitH,top" type="application/pdf">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            alt : <a href="<%= App.CONTEXT_PATH + '/api/certificadoOrigen/' + idFacturaF1%>">CO.pdf</a>
        </object>
    </div>
```

And this is the controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/certificadoOrigen/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
public Object getPDFCo(final @PathVariable("id") Long id, final HttpServletRequest request) {

    try {
       // sentences where build the pdf object...

        final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.put("Content-Type", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8" }));
        final ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(pdf, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
//Here I want to capture the message errors
    }
```

The question is, how I can capture and show the error messages to users?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Will this link help you, [displaying error message in login page after login failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903765/displaying-error-message-in-login-page-after-login-failure)

in summary, put the errorMessage in the request and get it on your page.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I need capture the response in my template, but the object response is not avaliable there.